# Jquery script in Google Chrome is not resizing text

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to run Jquery script that will resize text on click event.Here is my code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var os=$('p').css('font-size');
    var uom=os.slice(-2);
    var num=parseFloat(os,10);
    $('p').css('font-size', num /1.4 + uom);
    if(this.id == "zoom") {
        $('p').css('font-size', num * 1.4 + uom)
    }
})
```

Problem is that the script is not working in  Google Chrome. In IE8 and FF8, it works perfectly. Why does this not work in Google Chrome?

Comment: Try adding `px` or `em` or whatever - `$('p').css('font-size',(num* 1.4 + uom)+'px');`

Comment: i can confirm that it works well in chrome 16

Answer (score 1):

That seems to work perfectly for me in **Google Chrome** as well just as you have it stated. http://jsfiddle.net/pBEsR/3/

What version of Google Chrome are you using? I'm using 16.0.912.63 m

Comment: Weird I am also using same version ad you. Chrome 16.0.912.63.

Comment: I found a solution. Problem was in developer tool kit which I modified with my custom settings (dark color theme,bigger font) I didn`t know that it will  also effect content of the page that is being loaded. So I just went through settings and modified only parts that are related to developer tool kit.

Comment: That is pretty weird. You should add the solution as an answer in case someone else runs into the same issue.